# Article Content formatting Issue with modules

Tags: articles, module

I faced a strange issue with Joomla default Articles option with custom module.

In joomla article section when I enter some text like 
Price is `$20`  its not displaying on the site front end. When I use with a space `$ 20` It  works fine.

This article is showing on the front end with custom module,

Like this article content is reading from DB using a custom module and out put like

```
echo $fullArticle = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $values->introtext);
```

This module is loading inside another article with `{loadposition mypostion}`

When I put $20 directly in any other article its works fine, I think using custom module and loading position time the Joomla thinks `$20` as a variable or something ?

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the function for `loadposition` but as you said, it would seem it's being treated as a variable. I would normally say echo it in single quotes but as this is HTML that isn't appropriate.

What you can do is, use the a HTML Entity. So rather than using `$`, use `&#36;`

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately this `&#36;` also not working, also how to tell clients to use `&#36;` instead of `$`, I think using a content plugin writing may help? :(

Comment: Ahh I see. Ok have created a new custom module with the text `Price = $20` and then in the article, loaded the module using `{loadposition price}` and it is displaying fine. I assume you're using Joomla 3.x. Maybe I have tested this using the wrong approach.

Comment: Im using `Joomla 1.7` :( the workflow is like, Created an article and its content is something like `$20` and some text. This article is loaded with custom module in that module using DB query and fetch article content display with `echo $fullArticle = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $values->introtext); ` And set the module position from module manager `'myposition'` then set it on another article using `{loadposition mypostion}`

Comment: Oh 1.7. Ok I will test on 2.5 and get back to you in a bit

Comment: I resolved the issue with content plugin , I already have a content plugin for other purpose(short code parsing) there I put something like, `$article_content = str_replace('$','&#36;',$article->text);` and its working :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. You should write a proper answer and accept it ;)